# Tex Live Utility blocking certain files from updating, failing to allow a complete update of ALL files

Tags: pdftex, texlive

For the last two days, the `TexLive` Utility has been failing to allow a complete update of ALL files when attempting to `Update All Packages`.

[image: Screen capture showing those files that refuse to be updated, with the exit status shown in the background.]

I've been able to `Update Selected Packages` within the larger list of files, but those files listed above, e.g. `noto` -> `collection-fontsextra` simply refuse to be updated, resulting in a `The update failed.` error shown above when using the `Update All Packages` option.

All other files updated normally using the `Update Selected Packages` option.

My Repository Address is set at: `https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/texlive/tlnet`. The same error occurs when using the `https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/systems/texlive/tlnet/` Repository Address, so it does *not* appear to be a repository issue.

Comment: why have you tagged this `miktex-update` when it is about TeXLive?

Comment: it should be useful to know exactly which version of texlive you are using? When did `ex Live Utility` last work as it should?

Comment: Version 1.53 (1.53) ... TeX Live Utility last worked 'as it should' a few days ago. How should I have tagged this issue? Thks.

Comment: I've recently upgraded to the new 2022 TexLive version. All is well!

Answer (score -1):

Solved!

I initially attempted to delete the `noto` package using the **MiKTeX Console.app**, but noticed in the log that the `noto` deletion failed because the `noto` package belonged to the `collection-fontsextra` package.

[image: MiKTeX Console.app showing TeX option to delete the noto package]

So, after failing to delete the `noto` package using **MiKTeX Console.app**, I had a look back at the `Tex Live Utility/Packages` list. Lo-and-behold, when I right-clicked on the `collection-fontsextra` package, I was presented with three options, one of which was the option to `Reinstall Selected Packages`.

[image: Tex Live Utility/Packages Reinstall Selected Packages]

It took quite a few minutes, but the progress bar kept moving, and after what seems to be long time for a download, the message 'Update Succeeded' (or some such) appeared.

Then, when I went back and selected `Tex Live Utility/Updates` it said `No Updates Available`.

So at least for now, it would appear that my immediate issue has been solved, but I'll have to wait until there are additional updates to know for sure if the `Update All Packages` will work as it should.

Thanks for reading.

P.S. I had a look back at the tlmgr.log file to check why the download took so long. Turns out there were 339 files updated during the almost 30 minutes for the `Reinstall Selected Packages` to complete. I have ***NO*** idea why there were 339 packages updated when I simply right-clicked on the `collection-fontsextra` package to then `Reinstall Selected Packages`. Wow! What is going on?

**Note:** Please review the comments below before wading into the world of `MiKTeX`, as pointed out by those with infinitely more knowledge and experience with the ins and outs of `Tex Live Utility` versus `MiKTeX`.

Comment: Erh, what does TeX Live Utility has to do with MikTeX Console? Those two does not have anythign to do with each other. It more sounds like you have two LaTeX installations. You should stick with just one.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the MiKTeX project page to understand what the project is about: https://miktex.org

Comment: I say again: TeX Live utility has **nothing** to do with miktex! It is a configuration front end for TeXLive/Mactex.

Comment: "MiKTeX's integrated package manager installs missing components from the Internet, if required. This allows you to keep your TeX installation as minimal as possible (“Just enough TeX”)." See: https://miktex.org  In essence, the MiKTeX Console.app allows the user to manage their collection of TeX files, just as the TeX Live Utility does, and is demonstrated above. Am I missing something? I am seeing this as a distinction without a difference, n'est-ce pas? As I've demonstrated above, they both allow for the user to manage their collection of TeX files, and can even draw from same mirror URL.

Comment: You answer makes absolutely no sense with the question you posed. The question is all about TeX Live Utility? Why are you then bringing MikTeX console into it? MikTeX console cannot update TeXLive/Mactex and vise versa.

Comment: @RosesBouquet They serve similar functions, but for different distributions. So if you install or update something with the MikTeX manager, the new files are only used if you start the MikTeX version of TeX while the TeX Live Manager installs/updates a separate version which is only used if you start the TeX Live version of TeX. Normally you don't want to have both installed since then you have everything twice and you have to be very careful to always use the right version

Comment: My apologies, as I am a relative newcomer to the SE stage and to LaTeX and Tex. I am NOT trying to argue the finer points re TeX Live Manager versus the MiKTeX Console.app. Just trying to fumble my way through to find a solution to an irritable issue that stood in my way to updating my TeX files. Before now, I hadn't even heard of the MiKTeX Console.app, and didn't know that I could right-click on an item in the Tex Live Utility/Packages list to reinstall a package. So please forgive me if I transgress ...

Comment: Sounds like I should NOT be using the MiKTeX Console.app to make changes to my TeX files as that will create two distinct lists of TeX files that I might not understand how to operate? Is that the jist of what you are saying? I had NO idea ... Thanks for the explanation. Any idea why when I updated the collection-fontsextra package there were 339 files that were updated?

Comment: That is exactlyu what we are saying. Currently you both have TeXLive/Mactex and miktex on your Mac. Unless you know what you're doing that will only lead to confusion. MikTeX console is to update miktex, and TeXLive Utility is for TeXLive. Collection-fontsextra contains more than just one font.

Comment: Thanks ... I've somehow managed to irritate two top-notch SE'rs ... won't look good on my resume/obituary ... I really had NO idea what I had fumbled/stumbled into ... thanks for the feedback to straighten out what I am doing. Should I NOT accept my own answer then to the question I posed? I realized somewhere along the line that there were at least at least 8 fonts within the collection-fontsextra package, but a bit surprised to find that there were actually 339! Thanks again ... things are a bit tense on both side of the Atlantic ... my apologies if I added to the tension.

Comment: You're not the first user to end up with more than one LaTeX installation by accident. And you will not be the last. You might want to redo your answer in case it might be relevant for others in the future.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger and daleif - Boy, what a misstep ... is there somewhere I can read about the distinction between the two ... and should I just delete the MiKTeX Console.app from my Mac? The last thing I would want to do is create a duplicate universe that might only complicate the errors I am already seeing ... thanks for pointing that all out. TeX is NOT my area of expertise by any means ... it's just keeping me from my work in the area where I am trying to make a difference ... Ugh!

Comment: @ Nicolas Martignoni - Thank you for your edit. Is there anything else I need to do to accept your suggested edit that I'm still seeing?